# TensorFlow not detecting GPU (Dell Vostro with NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060)

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

OS: Windows 10 (also tried with Ubuntu to no avail) 
CPU: Intel Core i7-8750H @ 2.2 GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 with Max-Q design 
Python version 3.8 
TensorFlow version 2.3.0 (I did install it with `tensorflow-gpu`)

Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
print("Num CPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('CPU')))
```

Result:

```
Num GPUs Available:  0
Num CPUs Available:  1
```

Any idea?

Comment: Have you installed CUDA?

Comment: If you're doing a conda install, anaconda will get the cudnn and cuda toolkit dependencies for you and add it to path. If you're installing with pip, you'll have to get all the dependencies manually. If you are working with tensorflow-gpu, I would highly recommend using anaconda. Here's how you could use it: https://towardsdatascience.com/tensorflow-gpu-installation-made-easy-use-conda-instead-of-pip-52e5249374bc

Comment: Yes, I have installed CUDA

Comment: Can you let us know version of CUDA and cuDNN installed?

Comment: I upgraded to Python 3.9.6 and now it works. thanks

Answer (score 0):

From Comments

> Issue was resolved after upgraded to Python 3.9.6 (paraphrased from
> Idan Tobis)

For the benefit of community providing tested build configuration

[image]